# Android: duplicate activity onBackPressed()

Tags: android

I'm just trying to verbally explain what trouble I'm having now instead of displaying the entire code, because I think it might be easier for you to figure out what the problem is.

I start with **Activity A**. When I click **button B** here, then I move to the **Activity C**. After configuring a few things in this activity I pressed the back button to get back to the previous **Activity A**.

Here's the `onBackPressed()` part in the **Activity B**.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     mediaPlayer.stop();
     mediaPlayer.release();
  }

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
  startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
  finish();
}
```

With that code I manage to get back to the previous one, the **Activity A**. But when I click the back button again in this **Activity A**, I find myself with the same **Activity A** with the pre-configuration status.

Here's the `onBackPressed()` in the **Activity A**.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  turnOffRingtone(RingtoneVolumeControl.PLAYER);
}

private void turnOffRingtone(MediaPlayer ringtone) {
  try {
    if (ringtone != null) {
      ringtone.stop();
      ringtone.release();
    }
  } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
      Log.i(ApplicationManager.LOG, e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: how you starting your activing?? startActivityForResult?

Comment: Are you using onActivityResult for intent result

Comment: Try `finishAffinity()` instead of `finish()` in your `ActivityB` if you no longer want your `Activity A` in stack

Comment: I tried `finishAffinity()` as well, and the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to work with startActivityForResult and onActivityResult you are doing a couple of things wrong from my understanding. First, when you start your B activity, you should do it with:

```
 startActivityForResult(intentB,1);
```

Once you are in your B activity, do your code logic, and when you are ready to go back to your previous activity(in this case using back pressed) you should do something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

And now, back in Activity A, you handle your response from activity B

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //Write youy code for your result
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this flag in intent while passing an intent from Activity A.It will clear the back stack

**intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this in activity B

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

try this one. Because you are starting one activity again in activity B **onBackPressed()**  so remove that code and put above code with you extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is could be happens if you don't properly `finish()` the Activity.

If you want to keep the `Activity A` from termination like in the Music Player app, you can use `android:launchMode=singleTask` attribute for your activity like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:label="ActivityA"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

It is because an Activity with `android:launchMode=singleTask` is allowed to have only one instance in your app.

If you want to send an Intent to an existing `Activity A`, you need to catch the intent by overriding [`onNewIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) in your `Activity A`.